# ¿Cómo modificar una funcion de clase hija de una clase heredada para modificar una variable privada de otra clase?

Tags: c++, herencia

Tengo una classe C que hereda de una clase B que fue descrito [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56406/c%C3%B3mo-modificar-una-funcion-de-clase-para-modificar-una-variable-privada-de-otra/56419#56419). Quiero hacer lo mismo que en esta pregunta para modificar una variable private de una otra clase A .

Antes, modificaba la variable private de A con una variable puntero de une clase B y con un getX() en la clase A que fue utilisado para asignar a la variable el puntero de la clase B.

```
void B::imprimer() {
    cout << "B::imprimer: " << pA->getX() << " " << y << endl;
    }
```

Hoy quiero hacer lo mismo para modificar la misma variable pero desde C y tengo problemas hacerlo

He traido :

```
class B {
private :
    A * pA;
    int y;
public:
    B(int, int);
    ~B();
    void imprimer();
    int getPA();
};

int B::getPA(){
    pA -> getX();
    return *pA;
}

void B::imprimer() {
    cout << "B::imprimer: " << pA->getX() << " " << y << endl;
    }

class C: public B {
private :
    int z;
public:
    C(int, int, int);
    ~C();
    void imprimer();

};

void C::imprimer() {
    cout << "C::imprimer: " << pA->getY() << " " << y << endl;
    }

C::C(int a, int b, int c) : B(a, a+b)
{
    cout << "++ C debut" << endl;
    z = c;
    cout << "++ C z = " << z << endl;
    cout << "++ C fin" << endl;
}

C::~C()
{
    cout << "-- C debut z = " << z << endl;
    cout << "-- C fin" << endl;
}
```

Utiliso un puntero que llama a pA, el puntero sobre getX() que me devuelve x, en una funcion int B::getPA() y me da las errores siguientes :

```
    $ g++ td4Exercice1_3.cpp -o td4Exercice1_3
td4Exercice1_3.cpp: In member function ‘int B::getY()’:
td4Exercice1_3.cpp:33:13: error: cannot convert ‘A’ to ‘int’ in return
     return *pA;
             ^
td4Exercice1_3.cpp: In member function ‘void C::imprimer()’:
td4Exercice1_3.cpp:22:6: error: ‘A* B::pA’ is private
  A * pA;
      ^
td4Exercice1_3.cpp:51:29: error: within this context
  cout << "C::imprimer: " << pA->getY() << " " << y << endl;
                             ^
td4Exercice1_3.cpp:51:33: error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘getY’
  cout << "C::imprimer: " << pA->getY() << " " << y << endl;
                                 ^
td4Exercice1_3.cpp:23:6: error: ‘int B::y’ is private
  int y;
      ^
td4Exercice1_3.cpp:51:50: error: within this context
  cout << "C::imprimer: " << pA->getY() << " " << y << endl;
```

Comment: Esta cosa no compila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ver, tu código presenta algunos errores:

```
class B {
private:
  A *pA;
public:
  int getPA( );
};

int B::getPA(){
  pA -> getX();
  return *pA;
}
```

Eso es claramente incorrecto. Si `pA` es del tipo `A *`, **no puedes** devolverlo como `int`.

Además, si quieres acceder a los miembros internos, lo mas simple es declararlos como `protected`, con lo que quedaría así:

```
class B {
private :
  A * pA;

protected:
  int y;

public:
  B(int, int);
  ~B();
  void imprimer();
  A *getPA();
};

A* B::getPA(){
  return pA;
}
```

Y cambiar también

```
void C::imprimer() {
  cout << "C::imprimer: " << getPA()->getX() << " " << B::y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Buenas anotaciones. Yo desde el móvil me he limitado a lo mínimo

Comment: @eferion he observado tus últimas 3 respuestas *a toda pastilla*. Yo estoy muy códomo en mi sofá ;-)

Comment: Lo que da de si el móvil... El ordenador para contestar cómodo está a dos horas en coche

Comment: En esta pregunta en concreto, publicaste tu respuesta mientras que yo estaba editando la mía, que publiqué accidentalmente antes de estar correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Declara la variable como `protected` en vez de como `private`:

```
class B {
  protected:
    A * pA;
};
```

El modificador `protected` hace que los elementos sean públicos para las clases hijas mientras que los mismos son privados para el resto de clases.